# why do apps show a GPS start button?

Tags: android, gps

If you look at apps such as Google Maps app on Android, it display a gps icon, that when clicked starts the gps. However, if I don't click that image, and I move, it tracks me anyway. So what is the purpose of they button which we see in so many apps? Does the phone rely on GPS only when that button is pressed, or do they use the button, because they start the gps  every x minutes, so if you click the button, it start it immediately?
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPS radio is not started automatically.

When the GPS is off, the phone uses nearby WiFi nodes to find the location. That works pretty well in areas where there are a lot of known WiFi nodes, but the GPS is more exact, and works pretty much everywhere.

Comment: are you sure it is wifi nodes? How does that work? I can understand if you mean phone-cells, but how would this work with wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Applications like google maps have the gps logo because you may want to be shown your location, usually the application will try and find your location based on wifi and networks first and then using gps. The button will tell the app you want to know the location then and there and that's why it starts, other then that it should just do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

GPS isn't the only way to track a phone. When you don't have GPS enabled (or if your phone doesn't have a GPS chip in it), the cell phone can triangulate it's distance from the nearby cell towers. It can also do the same thing with nearby WiFi networks.

Since GPS takes up so much power, apps will ask you to enable GPS yourself instead of automatically enabling it when the app starts/runs in the background.

You can read more about common phone tracking methods here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking